# Having a global variable available to your templates in Django

Tags: python, django

I would like to have a common variable available to all my templates. I've been working on this all morning and the only way I can find to do it is to have middleware like this:

```
class GetNameMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_template_response(self, request, response):
        response.context_data['name'] = 'dave'
        return response
```

and have a view like this:

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'home.html', {})
```

and then I can access it in the template

```
Hello {{ name }}
```

It just seems a bit ugly that I can't use `render` any more *(I know I can do `from django.template.response import TemplateResponse as render` but that's not really a solution)*

*(Django 1.10, python 3.5.2)*

Comment: Could you add something about _why_ you need this? Because I think it's usually solved differently.

Comment: Yeah sure. I want to display a message across the site for people that are outside of the UK. The message needs common data like `{% if country_code != 'UK' %}...{% endif %}`

Comment: I agree with [giorgosp](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2924320/giorgosp) on the [custom context provider](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors). Here is a [helpful blog post](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/). While that post is dated, the contract, if you will, for the context provider functionality remains the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Django has a standard way for implementing this, which is context processors. This article provides an example implementation 
https://www.webforefront.com/django/setupdjangocontextprocessors.html.

Actually a context processor is just a function that accepts a request object and returns a dict with the data you want.

Comment: context processor is exactly what I was looking for. Job Done!